# Process/Synchronize from the server side of a lightswitch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I'm developing a Visual Studio Light Switch application which tracks employees, their skills, the projects they've worked on, the training they've received, and various other properties related to staffing and training.

Most of the information is unique to the application, but the canonical source for the current projects and employees is obviously not my application. I also don't want users of my application to have to keep the list of users and projects in sync, and instead would like to load/synchronized this data from the central company database.

Where can I plug in code on the server side to perform a task like this? Optimally I'd like this to run automatically on a regular scheduled basis. But I'd be content with something I have to manually trigger from the HTML Client for the time being just to get something working

Comment: Do you really need to synchronize the data? Wouldn't it be simpler to add the database containing users and projects to the Lightswitch application as an external data source?

Comment: The external data is not in a database. In one case the data is accessible through a REST web server, and in another it's just a big XML file hosted on a web server. I think it might be possible to expose this to my light switch project through a custom WCF RIA Service?

Comment: If the REST service is ODATA compatible, you could probably attach to it directly as a data source. Otherwise, yes I think you'd need to look at WCF RIA (or WebAPI) for REST and XML data, possibly with a custom extension for XML (this is an interesting article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290137.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2). Something of a learning curve but worth it because once you have them as server side data sources, you unlock all the automagic Lightswitch client interface goodies.